# Is it possible for .gcloudignore in Google Cloud to skip updating a file?

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have just started developing a Golang app, and have deployed it on Google App Engine. But, when I try to connect my local server to CloudSQL instance through proxy, I am able to connect only through TCP.

However, when connecting with the same CloudSQL instance in AppEngine, I am able to connect only through UNIX.

To cope with this, I have made changes in my local environment handler file, so that it can adapt to local and GCloud config, but I'm not sure how I can skip the update on just this file for GCloud? Again, I don't want AppEngine to delete this file, I just want the CLI to avoid uploading the new version of the handler file.

I use this command for deploying: `gcloud app deploy`

Currently, I deploy directly to AppEngine, instead of pushing it through VCS. Also, if there is an option to detect if the app is running on AppEngine, then it'd be really great.

TIA

Comment: Why not just temporarily remove the file from your project folder, run your deploy and then put the file back? or you can add the file to your ```skip_files``` section in app.yaml so that it is skipped during deployment and then when you are done, you remove the entry from your app.yaml file?

Comment: So, the requirement is to have the older version on server, and newer version on my local system. If I skip the file, the deployment would fail. I had tried putting the Handler file in .gcloudignore, but that completely skipped the file, instead of not uploading the newer version.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can achieve what you want short of a manual process i.e. have the version you want in the project folder, deploy and then change back to the version you want to keep on your local folder.

Comment: I found a workaround. We need not do that. Since I was unable to use Environment variables listed, I went to Cloud Shell to investigate the environment variables set there. And there, I found one which suited my needs. So now, I check that and accordingly determine if its prod or local environment in the code

Answer (score 1):

Got it, in case anyone gets stuck in such situation, we can make use of environment variables set in GCloud AppEngine. Although there is documentation stating the environment variables, I would still give importance to checking the environment variables in Cloud Console.

Documentation link for Go 1.12+ Runtime env:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/runtime